# Group multiple rows into one base on the value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to group multiple rows into one based on the value of a column.

Given this data:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, RoomId , [Event], EventDate 
FROM TimeLog
WHERE EmployeeID = '107733' 
  AND EventDate BETWEEN '2020/02/26 00:00:00' AND  '2020/02/26 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY EventDate
```

| EmployeeID | RoomID | Event | EventDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 107733 | 05-27F | Login | 2020-02-26 07:02:00 |
| 107733 | 05-27F | Logout | 2020-02-26 08:38:00 |
| 107733 | 05-25F | Login | 2020-02-26 08:39:00 |
| 107733 | 05-25F | Logout | 2020-02-26 08:51:00 |
| 107733 | 05-27F | Login | 2020-02-26 08:52:00 |
| 107733 | 05-27F | Logout | 2020-02-26 12:00:00 |

So based on the value of the **Event** column which contains 2 possible values - **Login** and **Logout**, I want to combine 2 rows into one so that the result would be something like this:

| EmployeeID | RoomID | Login | Logout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 107733 | 05-27F | 2020-02-26 07:02:00 | 2020-02-26 08:38:00 |
| 107733 | 05-25F | 2020-02-26 08:39:00 | 2020-02-26 08:51:00 |
| 107733 | 05-27F | 2020-02-26 08:52:00 | 2020-02-26 12:00:00 |

Additional Requirement (if possible):

- It should be sorted chronologically
- (EDGE CASE) In case "Login" is missing or has no value, it should get the value of the Logout, same if "Logout" has no value - it should get the value of the "Login" field. So Login and Logout will have the same value if one is missing.

| EmployeeID | RoomID | Event | EventDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 107733 | 05-27F | Login | 2020-02-26 07:02:00 |
| 107733 | 05-25F | Logout | 2020-02-26 08:38:00 |

Note that in this case, this happens in different "Room". On 05-27F there's no Logout, while in 05-25F there's no Login. Expected result would be:

| EmployeeID | RoomID | Login | Logout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 107733 | 05-27F | 2020-02-26 07:02:00 | 2020-02-26 07:02:00 |
| 107733 | 05-25F | 2020-02-26 08:38:00 | 2020-02-26 08:38:00 |

My attempt to solve this problem:

```
SELECT 
    EmployeeID, 
    RoomID, 
    'Login' = (SELECT TOP 1 EventDate 
               FROM TimeLog li 
               WHERE li.EmployeeID = tl.EmployeeID 
                 AND li.RoomID = tl.RoomID 
                 AND li.[Event] = 1),
    'Logout' = (SELECT TOP 1 EventDate 
                FROM TimeLog lo 
                WHERE lo.EmployeeID = tl.EmployeeID 
                  AND lo.RoomID = tl.RoomID 
                  AND lo.[Event] = 2)
FROM  
    TimeLog tl
WHERE 
    tl.EmployeeID = '107733'
    AND tl.EventDate BETWEEN '2020/02/26 00:00:00' AND '2020/02/26 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt to achieve your expected output?

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple login/logout events for the same employee & room combo?

Comment: @lemon i've updated the details

Comment: @JohnLBevan yes there is, if employee re-enters the same room after he/she logs out. I;ve expanded my test data to show this - please check details again.

Comment: What does that code have to do with your goal? What part does it do exactly? How are you stuck going further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should do what you're after: [DBFiddle Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/XESCnyBr)

```sql
with cte as (
  select row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId, RoomId order by EventDate) r
  , *
  from TimeLog
)
select coalesce(i.EventDate, o.EventDate) LoginDate
, coalesce(o.EventDate, i.EventDate) LogoutDate
, coalesce(i.EmployeeId, o.EmployeeId) EmployeeId_
, coalesce(i.RoomId, o.RoomId)  RoomId_
from (select * from cte where Event = 'Login') i
full outer join (select * from cte where Event = 'Logout') o
on o.EmployeeId = i.EmployeeId
and o.RoomId = i.RoomId
and o.r = i.r+1
order by LoginDate, LogoutDate, EmployeeId_, RoomId_
```

This works by sequencing the events per employee/room combination.

If a logout appears immediately after a login (i.e. the sequence number (r) or the logout event is 1 more than that for the login event) then the 2 are related & put in the same row.

If you get any rows with a login that doesn't have an consecutive logout, or a logout without an immediately prior login, those are seen as having missing data, so you get null in the corresponding logout time / login time columns.

Hope that makes sense & helps - let me know if you need a deeper explation of anything.

---

Code to create demo data

```sql
create table TimeLog (
  EmployeeId bigint not null,
  RoomId nchar(6) not null,
  Event nvarchar(6) not null,
  EventDate DateTime not null
)
```

```sql
insert TimeLog (EmployeeID, RoomId, Event, EventDate)
values (107733, '05-27F',   'Login',    '2020-02-26 07:02:00')
     , (107733, '05-27F',   'Logout',   '2020-02-26 08:38:00')
     , (107733, '05-25F',   'Login',    '2020-02-26 08:39:00')
     , (107733, '05-25F',   'Logout',   '2020-02-26 08:51:00')
     , (107733, '05-25F',   'Login',    '2020-02-27 08:39:00')
     , (107733, '05-25F',   'Logout',   '2020-02-27 08:51:00')
     , (107733, '05-25X',   'Login',    '2020-02-27 08:39:00')
     , (107733, '05-25Y',   'Logout',   '2020-02-27 08:51:00')
```

Example output

| LoginDate | LogoutDate | EmployeeId_ | RoomId_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-02-26 07:02:00.000 | 2020-02-26 08:38:00.000 | 107733 | 05-27F |
| 2020-02-26 08:39:00.000 | 2020-02-26 08:51:00.000 | 107733 | 05-25F |
| 2020-02-27 08:39:00.000 | 2020-02-27 08:39:00.000 | 107733 | 05-25X |
| 2020-02-27 08:39:00.000 | 2020-02-27 08:51:00.000 | 107733 | 05-25F |
| 2020-02-27 08:51:00.000 | 2020-02-27 08:51:00.000 | 107733 | 05-25Y |

## Answer for follow-up question

Try this: [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/88EMMziU)

```sql
with LoginCte as (
  select row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId, RoomId order by EventDate) LoginNo
  , EmployeeId
  , RoomId
  , EventDate LoginDate
  from TimeLog
  where Event = 'Login'
)
, LogoutCte as (
  select count(icte.LoginNo) PriorLoginCount
  , octe.EmployeeId
  , octe.RoomId
  , EventDate LogoutDate
  from TimeLog octe
  left outer join LoginCte icte 
  on icte.EmployeeId = octe.EmployeeId
  and icte.RoomId = octe.RoomId
  where Event = 'Logout'
  group by octe.EmployeeId, octe.RoomId, octe.Eventdate
)
select coalesce(i.EmployeeId, o.EmployeeId) EmployeeId_
, coalesce(i.RoomId, o.RoomId) RoomId_
, LoginDate
, LogoutDate
from LoginCte i
full outer join logoutCte o
on o.EmployeeId = i.EmployeeId
and o.RoomId = i.RoomId
and o.PriorLoginCount = i.LoginNo
```

This works by giving each login a sequential id as before; for the the logouts it counts how many logins appear before it.  These numbers can then be combined to ensure the latest login is always paired with its earliest corresponding logout; without losing any records.

i.e.

- Any logout records which occur before the first login will have `priorLoginCount` of `0`.
- The first login record has `loginNo` of `1`.  All logout records which occur after that login but before the next login have `priorLoginCount` of `1`.
- The second login record has `loginNo` of `2`.  All logout records which occur after that login but before the third login have `priorLoginCount` of `2`.
- If we have any login records after the last logout records they'll have `loginNo` values higher than any of the logout records `priorLoginCount` values.

As such, we can pair our records up on these values.

Comment: No worries - FYI: I just tweaked it per your edge case (i.e. so instead of nulls for missing values you get the login/logout date repeated)

Comment: This works perfect! Amazing you solved it in no time.. Will just need to test this in large amount of data (if there will be perf issue in execution). thanks again! Im trying to understand how this works but CTEs really hard to grasp

Comment: In this scenario the CTE's just a way to avoid repeating the same subquery a couple of times; it could be replaced by a view with the same logic.  e.g. `create view cteLogicAsView as select row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId, RoomId order by EventDate) r  , *  from TimeLog`

Comment: The `row_number() over (partition by EmployeeId, RoomId order by EventDate) r` bit just says get all the records for a given `employeeid` and `roomid` combo, order those records by `eventdate` and number them starting at `1` / do the same for all `employeeid` & `roomid` combos.

Comment: And then the `o.r = i.r+1` thing, is this to check the next "row"?, logout row = login row + 1 right?

Comment: Hi @JohnLBevan pardon but i have a follow up question, in the scenario where there's login entry but there's no logout.. is it possible to get the login on the next record instead of copying the login entry? same thing with logout without login, can we get the last logout instead?

Comment: RE: `o.r = i.r+1` yes, exactly that; i.e. to prove the events are consecutive, so you only get the logout that immediately follows its related login.

Comment: RE: Follow up... I'll try, but I not sure how efficient/clean my solution will be; that feels much more complex...

Comment: Done... Think that works.  Note: I included in the dbfiddle a solution that doesn't work, just in case that's of interest / to see an idea of an attempt that didn't play out: https://dbfiddle.uk/88EMMziU

Answer (score 0):

If you're firmly in SQL Server world, PIVOT is also an option here:

```
SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    RoomID,
    ISNULL([Login], [Logout]) AS LatestLogin,
    ISNULL([Logout], [Login]) AS LatestLogout
FROM
    TimeLog
PIVOT (
    MAX(EventDate)
    FOR Event IN ([Login], [Logout])
    ) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY
    LatestLogin
;
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, RoomId,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Event = 'Login'  THEN EventDate ELSE NULL END) AS LatestLogin,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Event = 'Logout' THEN EventDate ELSE NULL END) AS LatestLogout,
FROM Wherever
GROUP BY EmployeeID, RoomId
```

Update: first login and last logout on each day.

```
SELECT w.EmployeeID, w.RoomId, d.Date,
    MIN(CASE WHEN Event = 'Login'  THEN EventDate ELSE NULL END) AS LatestLogin,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Event = 'Logout' THEN EventDate ELSE NULL END) AS LatestLogout
FROM Wherever w
    INNER JOIN (
        -- Find the dates. This is the PK of the result.
        DISTINCT EmployeeId, RoomId, CAST(EventDate AS date) AS Date
        FROM Wherever
    ) AS d
        ON w.EmployeeId = d.EmployeeId AND w.RoomId = d.RoomId AND CAST(w.EventDate AS date) = w.LatestDate
GROUP BY w.EmployeeID, w.RoomId, d.Date
```

Comment: Thanks! but this seems to only get the "First Login" and "Last Logout"? there could be instance where employee reenters the same room in a day.